# how to render rails form by jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to render follow and unfollow forms into rails view

Create.js.erb ( my problem is here as this is wrong code only acts on CSS not the rails forms and I can't seem to handle it D:)

```
$('.btn-danger').attr('class', 'btn')
                   .val('Following')
                   .attr('id', 'btn-unfollow');
```

destroy.js.erb ( also this is wrong code only acts on CSS, not the rails forms )

```
$('.btn').attr('class', 'btn-danger')
                   .val('unfollowed')
                   .attr('id', 'btn-follow');
```

my Postsindex.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |f| %>
<%= f.headline %>
<%- f.text %> 
    <% if current_user.id != f.user.id %>
    <% if !current_user.following?(f.user) %>
    <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build, remote: true) do |s| %>
      <div> <%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, f.user.id %> </div>
      <%= s.button "follow", class: "btn btn-danger", id: "follow-btn" %>
      <% end %>
      <% else %>
      <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: f.user.id), :html => {method: :delete}, remote: true) do |s| %>
      <%= s.button "unfollow", class: "btn", id: "unfollow-btn", remote: true %>
      <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <% end %>

<% end %>
```

posts controller :

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 def new
    @post = Post.new
  end
def index
@posts = post.all
end
end
```

The only problem is that follow and unfollow are not on partials but rather on same page so if i can render each of them separatley I will be thankful ...

Comment: Not an answer, but why do you call ‘f’ each post, and then you call ‘s’ the form? Besides that, I don’t understand the problem. Why do you use forms instead of simple links? It’s just a link or button to follow or unfollow, isn’t it?

Comment: no sir because following is like +1 must be added to database so that you can retrieve posts for people you follow later on ...

Comment: You can do a simple link or button that makes an Ajax call to your controller and follows or unfollows (adds or removed from the database) the user. You don’t need a form because you don’t need to ask any data to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like below for your situation. Hope you'll find that solution helpful too.

1. Create a separate controller `followersController`. It'll handle the all follow/unfollow related activities. (I believe you've created a model too)
2. Try to respond the view with `:js` in controller
3. So, If someone hits **follow** button then the `controller > create` method will be hit. After create change the view by rendering a js file named `create.js.erb` and write appropriate code.
4. When someone hits **unfollow** button then the `controller > destroy` method will be hit. After create change the view by rendering a js file named `destroy.js.erb` and write appropriate code.
5. In view, try to use different `id` in the follow/unfollow button so that in the js file you can handle the `selectors` easily.

In the **create.js.erb** file, you should do something like that:

```
$('#follow_button_parent_div').html("<%=j render partial: 'unfollow_button_html_file' %>")
```

in **_unfollow_button_html_file.html.erb**, write a `<form></form>` with unfollow button as submit to destroy the recently created follow record.

for destroy section, modify codes accordingly.

Comment: will I already have the followcontroller and this is not m problem my question is how can change the follow button to unfollow on click ( changing the code so it can delete the follow relationship from data base ) and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. Please change to adapt to your models and fields in your database

**Posts view:**
I would make two links to follow or unfollow. Only one is visible (depending on the author of the post and if I am already following him). These links would make a ajax post to follow/unfollow the author of the post and will switch links (hides himself and shows the other link)

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.headline %>
  <%- post.text %> 
  <% if current_user.id != post.user.id %>
    <%= render partial: 'follow_links', locals: { user: post.user }
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Partial follow_links.**

```
<% show_follow_link   = current_user.following?(user) ? 'hidden' : '' %>
<% show_unfollow_link = current_user.following?(user) ? '' : 'hidden' %>

<!-- links to follow/unfollow have data-attributes that include the path to make the ajax post and the user to follow, that is used to find the link to show after the ajax call -->
<%= link_to 'Follow',   '#', { class: 'follow-user btn-success #{show_follow_link}', "data-url": follow_user_path(user.id), "data-followee": user.id } %>
<%= link_to 'Unfollow', '#', { class: 'unfollow-user btn-danger #{show_unfollow_link}', "data-url": unfollow_user_path(user.id), "data-followee": user.id } %>
```

**Javascript for the partial**

```
$('.follow-user').on("click",function() {
  target = $(this)
  url = target.attr('data-url')
  followee = target.attr('data-followee')
  other_button = $('.unfollow-user[data-followee="'+followee+'"]')

  $.ajax( {
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    success: function() {
      target.addClass('hidden');
      other_button.removeClass('hidden');
    },
    error: function(ret) {
      alert(ret.responseJSON.error);
    }
  });

});

$('.unfollow-user').on("click",function() {
  target = $(this)
  url = target.attr('data-url')
  followee = target.attr('data-followee')
  other_button = $('.follow-user[data-followee="'+followee+'"]')

  $.ajax( {
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    success: function() {
      target.addClass('hidden');
      other_button.removeClass('hidden');
    },
    error: function(ret) {
      alert(ret.responseJSON.error);
    }
  });
```

**UsersController (new methods to follow and unfollow)**

```
def follow
  if !current_user
    render json: { :error => 'You must log in' }, :status => :unprocessable_entity
    return
  end

  who_to_follow = User.find_by id: params[:id]
  if !who_to_follow
    render json: { :error => 'User not found' }, :status => :not_found
    return
  end

  # Change user_id by the field in the relationship that links to the followee
  followee = current_user.active_relationships.create(user_id: who_to_follow.id)
  render json: who_to_follow, :status => :ok
  return
end


def unfollow

  if !current_user
    render json: { :error => 'You must log in' }, :status => :unprocessable_entity
    return
  end

  who_to_unfollow = User.find_by id: params[:id]
  if !who_to_unfollow
    render json: { :error => 'User not found' }, :status => :not_found
    return
  end

  # Change user_id by the field in the relationship that links to the followee
  unfollowee = current_user.active_relationships.find_by user_id: who_to_unfollow.id

  if !unfollowee
    render json: { :error => 'You are not  following this user' }, :status => :unprocessable_entity
    return
  end

  unfollowee.destroy
  render json: who_to_unfollow, :status => :ok
  return

end
```

**Add routes**

```
post  "/users/:id/follow"    => 'users#follow',   :as => :follow_user
post  "/users/:id/unfollow"  => 'users#unfollow', :as => :unfollow_user
```